# jQuery / Tumblr - parsing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-scraping, tumblr

I'm trying to read Tumblr informations via the JSON API (and recuperate the total numbers of post for a blog)

My JS code looks like this:

```
 $.getJSON("http://demo.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function(json) { 
    $('.counter').html(json.posts-total);
 });
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: I can't recuperate the total nb of posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$.getJSON("http://demo.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function(json) { 
    $('.counter').text(json["posts-total"]);
});
```

Since `-` is an operator, JavaScript would otherwise try to subtract `total` from `json.posts`.

You can see this working in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hn2pH/)

Answer (score -1):

not worked with tumblr but an easier way to use jQuery to get json data is

```
$.get( "http://demo.tumblr.com/api/read/json", {callback:"?"}, function(data){
    alert( data.posts-total )
}, "json");
```

maybe a different approch will help, also the console of firebug is very valiuable in seeing why an ajax request hasn't worked. Maybe check that too firebug->console

if none of this helps shoot back a little more info and will see what else can be a miss..

Comment: This does not identify the issue, nor does it fix it.